# Flutter background image for Container is not coming

Tags: flutter, dart

I am trying to set a background image for the Login page using Container. But the background image is not coming. Am I missing something in my code? Are there image standards for flutter? I have no error with Pub get. Please guide.

Below is my code under Container DecorationImage I set my assets image with BoxFit.cover. But the image coming white. With my pubspec.yaml  I set  assets: - assets/ and Pub get is OK.

Please check my code I am just New to Flutter

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class MyLogin extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyLogin({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _MyLoginState createState() => _MyLoginState();
}

class _MyLoginState extends State<MyLogin> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      decoration: BoxDecoration(
        image: DecorationImage(
            image: AssetImage('assets/login.png'), fit: BoxFit.cover),
      ),
      child: Scaffold(
        backgroundColor: Colors.transparent,
        body: Stack(
          children: [
            Container(),
            Container(
              padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 35, top: 130),
              child: Text(
                'Welcome\nBack',
                style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white, fontSize: 33),
              ),
            ),
            SingleChildScrollView(
              child: Container(
                padding: EdgeInsets.only(
                    top: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * 0.5),
                child: Column(
                  crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                  children: [
                    Container(
                      margin: EdgeInsets.only(left: 35, right: 35),
                      child: Column(
                        children: [
                          TextField(
                            style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black),
                            decoration: InputDecoration(
                                fillColor: Colors.grey.shade100,
                                filled: true,
                                hintText: "Email",
                                border: OutlineInputBorder(
                                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
                                )),
                          ),
                          SizedBox(
                            height: 30,
                          ),
                          TextField(
                            style: TextStyle(),
                            obscureText: true,
                            decoration: InputDecoration(
                                fillColor: Colors.grey.shade100,
                                filled: true,
                                hintText: "Password",
                                border: OutlineInputBorder(
                                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
                                )),
                          ),
                          SizedBox(
                            height: 40,
                          ),
                          Row(
                            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                            children: [
                              Text(
                                'Sign in',
                                style: TextStyle(
                                    fontSize: 27, fontWeight: FontWeight.w700),
                              ),
                              CircleAvatar(
                                radius: 30,
                                backgroundColor: Color(0xff4c505b),
                                child: IconButton(
                                    color: Colors.white,
                                    onPressed: () {},
                                    icon: Icon(
                                      Icons.arrow_forward,
                                    )),
                              )
                            ],
                          ),
                          SizedBox(
                            height: 40,
                          ),
                          Row(
                            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                            children: [
                              TextButton(
                                onPressed: () {
                                  Navigator.pushNamed(context, 'register');
                                },
                                child: Text(
                                  'Sign Up',
                                  textAlign: TextAlign.left,
                                  style: TextStyle(
                                      decoration: TextDecoration.underline,
                                      color: Color(0xff4c505b),
                                      fontSize: 18),
                                ),
                                style: ButtonStyle(),
                              ),
                              TextButton(
                                  onPressed: () {},
                                  child: Text(
                                    'Forgot Password',
                                    style: TextStyle(
                                      decoration: TextDecoration.underline,
                                      color: Color(0xff4c505b),
                                      fontSize: 18,
                                    ),
                                  )),
                            ],
                          )
                        ],
                      ),
                    )
                  ],
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

I have tried to run the code and its running fine and all the controls are coming but the background images are not coming.

Comment: I've tested with network image, it is working fine, can you recheck the path

Comment: Your code is inefficient. There is no reason to have a Container with the child Scaffold. Return Scaffold directly, and then put your Container with the image into Stack. It won't solve the image problem, but your code will be better.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this way containing these changes,

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class MyLogin extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyLogin({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _MyLoginState createState() => _MyLoginState();
}

class _MyLoginState extends State<MyLogin> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Container(
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
          image: DecorationImage(
            image: AssetImage('assets/login.png'),
            fit: BoxFit.cover,
          ),
        ),
        child: Scaffold(
          backgroundColor: Colors.transparent,
          body: Stack(
            children: [
              Container(),
              Container(
                padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 35, top: 130),
                child: Text(
                  'Welcome\nBack',
                  style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white, fontSize: 33),
                ),
              ),
              SingleChildScrollView(
                child: Container(
                  padding: EdgeInsets.only(
                      top: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * 0.5),
                  child: Column(
                    crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                    children: [
                      Container(
                        margin: EdgeInsets.only(left: 35, right: 35),
                        child: Column(
                          children: [
                            TextField(
                              style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black),
                              decoration: InputDecoration(
                                  fillColor: Colors.grey.shade100,
                                  filled: true,
                                  hintText: "Email",
                                  border: OutlineInputBorder(
                                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
                                  )),
                            ),
                            SizedBox(
                              height: 30,
                            ),
                            TextField(
                              style: TextStyle(),
                              obscureText: true,
                              decoration: InputDecoration(
                                  fillColor: Colors.grey.shade100,
                                  filled: true,
                                  hintText: "Password",
                                  border: OutlineInputBorder(
                                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
                                  )),
                            ),
                            SizedBox(
                              height: 40,
                            ),
                            Row(
                              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                              children: [
                                Text(
                                  'Sign in',
                                  style: TextStyle(
                                      fontSize: 27,
                                      fontWeight: FontWeight.w700),
                                ),
                                CircleAvatar(
                                  radius: 30,
                                  backgroundColor: Color(0xff4c505b),
                                  child: IconButton(
                                      color: Colors.white,
                                      onPressed: () {},
                                      icon: Icon(
                                        Icons.arrow_forward,
                                      )),
                                )
                              ],
                            ),
                            SizedBox(
                              height: 40,
                            ),
                            Row(
                              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                              children: [
                                TextButton(
                                  onPressed: () {
                                    Navigator.pushNamed(context, 'register');
                                  },
                                  child: Text(
                                    'Sign Up',
                                    textAlign: TextAlign.left,
                                    style: TextStyle(
                                        decoration: TextDecoration.underline,
                                        color: Color(0xff4c505b),
                                        fontSize: 18),
                                  ),
                                  style: ButtonStyle(),
                                ),
                                TextButton(
                                    onPressed: () {},
                                    child: Text(
                                      'Forgot Password',
                                      style: TextStyle(
                                        decoration: TextDecoration.underline,
                                        color: Color(0xff4c505b),
                                        fontSize: 18,
                                      ),
                                    )),
                              ],
                            )
                          ],
                        ),
                      )
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Yes this one working. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

- Make sure the asset image is existing.
- You should change Container -> Scaffold into Scaffold -> Container or Scaffold -> Stack -> Container.